# Is there an algorithm to separate both foreground and backgound of an image using opencv

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing

Is there an algorithm to separate both foreground and background of an image using open-CV?

Can some one help me? I am confused about where to find the solution.

I am using **open-CV**

Comment: what kind of scenes (laboratory/indoor/outdoor)? single image or multiple images (e.g. video) of one scene?

Comment: indoor for multiple images (video). @Micka  is there any solution to find out scenes , i am working on stigmatization of videos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! You can do something called background subtraction. You can find a complete tutorial on the OpenCV website [here](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/video/background_subtraction/background_subtraction.html)

This tutorial shows you how to:

- Read data from videos by using VideoCapture or image sequences by
  using imread;
- Create and update the background model by using BackgroundSubtractor class;
- Get and show the foreground mask by using imshow;
- Save the output by using imwrite to quantitatively evaluate the results.

Answer (score 0):

In case a clean plate background is unavailable, making background subtraction unfeasible (though you could still use an adaptive background segmentation approach), you can go for a graph cut based approach, such as OpenCV's [grabcut](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_grabcut/py_grabcut.html) function.

This is an interactive segmentation algorithm which requires the user to create a bounding box for the foreground and (optionally) mark some pixels as seeds for the foreground, and then performs a graph cut - first it models the image as a graph and solves a min-cut algorithm to yield the segmentation. I've found the OpenCV implementation to work very well even for challenging images with reasonable color separability around the desired foreground borders.

Once you've obtained the foreground, you only need to subtract this from the original image to obtain the background. Hope this helps.